# Http get request with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, get

I check my sections with get methods on my site, the thing is, I want the sections to change automatically at certain intervals, so I started researching how to use the http get method with javascript, but I haven't found an answer yet, my codes are as follows

```
        <div style="margin-left:25%; width: 10%; text-align: center;">   <!--min-width: min-content;-->
        <a href="#AnaSayfa" onclick="myfunction();"  style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; ">
              
               
                <div style="transform: translatey(50%); margin-top: 0px; width: auto;height: max-content; font-size: 24px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Tahoma; color:white;">Ana Sayfa</div>

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: chartreuse;" id="Anasayfa"> </section>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: chartreuse;" id="Anasayfa-2"> </section>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: chartreuse;" id="Anasayfa-3"> </section>
```

Comment: Hi, What do you mean exactly? Are you trying to fetch some data using javascript and adding it to HTML? You can use Ajax

Comment: actually i want to use get method with javascript
In this way, I will be able to switch using the id of my sections.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't share how you are using get. But you can use Ajax as @ali said. Basically Ajax or XMLHttpRequest you can do:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // In local files, status is 0 upon success in Mozilla Firefox
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
      // The request has been completed successfully
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      // Oh no! There has been an error with the request!
    }
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

here `onreadystatechange` fires off each time the `readystate` changes.
`readystate` can have 5 values:

```
0 is UNSENT, i.e the req is stll not established
1 is OPENED, the req to the server is being opend
2 is HEADERS_RECEIVED, we have got back the haeders
3 is LOADING, the data is coming from server.
4 is DONE, the whole operation is complete.
```

with the help of these state changes you can do stuff on a specific interval.

You can find the readystate list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)!

You can learn a lot more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: href="#HomePage" in the line of code I shared
The id calls my homepage section. I have multiple sections and I want them to change every 30 seconds. I want to activate #Homepage-1 and #Homepage-2 with the get method from java.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any request.

You can control the elements on the page with `document`

```js
const sections = ['Anasayfa', 'Anasayfa-2', 'Anasayfa-3'];
let i = 0;

function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = 'none';
  i++;
  if (i === sections.length) { i = 0; }
  document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = 'block';
}

function auto() {
  myfunction();
  setInterval(myfunction, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  auto();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

section {
  display: none;
}

#Anasayfa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:25%; width: 10%; text-align: center;">   <!--min-width: min-content;-->
        <a href="#AnaSayfa" onclick="myfunction();"  style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; ">
              
               
                <div style="transform: translatey(50%); margin-top: 0px; width: auto;height: max-content; font-size: 24px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Tahoma; color:white;">Ana Sayfa</div>

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: chartreuse;" id="Anasayfa"> 1 </section>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red;" id="Anasayfa-2"> 2 </section>

<section style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;" id="Anasayfa-3"> 3 </section>
```

Comment: I totally understand what you're talking about, but my way of changing sections is a little different.

style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 10; width: 100%; min-width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(196, 124, 124);"

I blocked the expansion by putting max-width here and filled it, then I made overflow:hidden to hide the scrollbar for the user href=#...
I am checking it by directing it to the ids with s. Can I send what I want with a java command?
href="#somethink"

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand anything. You told you want to 'change automatically at certain intervals'. What do you mea by 'directing it to the ids with s'? Do you also want switch of section with link click? It is already there.

Comment: sorry for the bad translation i will try to be more descriptive


The thing is, I create changes on the screen by calling the ids of the sections with my own code. href=#mysection
but I want 5 sections on my homepage to change with certain seconds
display:block and display:none make sense, but I didn't use them while writing my code. How can I call section in javascript? When I do href=#mysection in html, it works. I want to do it in java.
thanks for ur support

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get an element in javascript.

- directly by the element id (`id` attribute of HTML)
- `document.getElementById(id)`
- `document.querySelector(cssSelector)`

Search with `getElement` in the page [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) for look for more options